# Hard Drive and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, external, hard-drive

I had a question about using Android Studio with an external hard drive on Windows 10. If I copy a full android project from my computer to the hard drive can I access the project from the hard drive if I delete the file from the computer itself (With hard drive still plugged in)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For My experience never delete original project you will needed at some point.

Yes you can access the project from the hard drive In Android Studio by Clicking File > Open select your drive and look for your file.
You will always able to see the project location it is Running from.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was not looking in the correct place to open the file :)

Answer (score 1):

Why bothering deleting the original file on your PC? It's never harmful to keep one backup, right?
But the answer to your question is yes. You should be able to access the project through the external drive as long as you keep it plugged in. Nothing different.

Comment: Yes, I do agree but I wanted to clear up some storage on my computer as I have the entire internal HDD filled up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you copy the project folder on a hard external hard drive you can access it normally. You just have to select it the same way as you would with a local project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Copy the project to the desired location. Delete the files on the internal HDD. Then launch (or relaunch) Android Studio. Go to File, Open Project, then set the new path to the project on the external HDD.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can always use an External hard drive for storage of Android projects. You just need to run it as usual as it is.
But, I will suggest you to use internal SSD drive for executing Android Project because it is much faster than using external HD drive.
Internal Disk start up time of Android studio is approximately 7 to 8 seconds, build times on apps of low/medium complexity were built in 5 seconds.
For external HD start up times were much higher, coming in at approximately 40 seconds. Build times on apps of low/medium complexity were built in 30 to 40 seconds mark.